# Is THESE is who I am or THIS is who I am

Tags: possessive-pronouns

I talked about my personality and likes and dislikes and story. At the end should I write it as **THIS** or **THESE** is who I am??

Answer (score 1):

You should write "**This** is who I am" because this information concerns you as a singular personality.

Furthermore, "**These** is who I am" would be ungrammatical. You'd have to change it to "**These are** who I am" and this would be quite illogical.

You can reformulate your sentence thus:

> **These facts** describe who I am.

Comment: Unless you had multiple personalities, I imagine.